# Как сделать такую grid разметку?

Tags: html, css, grid

Как сделать чтобы элементы на второй строке были по расположены по центру Grid?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.product__info{
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 700px;
    
}

.product__info__item{
    margin-top: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #D9D9D9;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__info">

    <div class="product__info__item"></div>
    <div class="product__info__item"></div>
    <div class="product__info__item"></div>
    <div class="product__info__item"></div>
    <div class="product__info__item"></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: По-моему сделать такое на flex будет проще, почему именно grid?

Comment: Думал наоборот, что на грид легче сделать

Comment: На флексах: `justify-content: center;` или `justify-content: space-evenly;` + `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.